# No Package Called tidytext in R

Tags: r, text, nlp

I'm attempting to load tidytext onto my version of r using the following syntax:

```
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
```

This is the message I recieve

```
Error in library(tidytext) : there is no package called ‘tidytext’
```

As far as I can tell tidytext is still an active library. Why can't I load it?

Here are the results of the R.Version()

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "5.2"

$year
[1] "2018"

$month
[1] "12"

$day
[1] "20"

$`svn rev`
[1] "75870"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)"

$nickname
[1] "Eggshell Igloo"
```

Comment: Is this a problem you've encountered with other packages, or is it exclusive to tidytext?

Comment: If you're using RStudio, is it listed as installed in the Packages pane? If not using RStudio, does it show up in `find.package("tidytext")` ? If not then it isn't installed - were there errors on installation?

Comment: @Dubarkay I've never encountered this before.  I've also loaded tidytext with no problems in the past.

Comment: It is a bit old version compared to R 4.0.4.  can you update your R version and install the package or if you want to install the tidytext, try a version that is more compatible i.e. from archives.  Even the oldest was released in [2019](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tidytext/).  So, updating the R version may be better

Comment: What is the output of `install.packages("tidytext")`? That's where an error is likely to occur if one is happening.